# Any sites/apps for sharing and rating hiking/hillwalking routes?

Tags: online-resources, hiking, walking, mobile-apps

In Germany, there are many hiking/hillwalking trails.

Are there any apps or sites that allow people to share hiking/hillwalking routes?

Where I can try to search for nice places people have been, or create my own routes ("I want to do a 20km hike in a circle, starting from within 50km of some town, and there should be a restaurant near the middle for lunch").

Sites like Strava for fitness allow you to share runs and cycle trips you've done.

Answer (score 1):

[Bergfex.com](http://www.bergfex.com/) is one of the major sites to do that. It allows you to plan on the map, share quality, photos and much more all over Europe, in several languages. I am not sure how hard it would be to create your own tracks however.